# Wake on Network for Alternate Ports

Tags: network, macos, sleep-wake, wake-on-lan

My ethernet wired 2012 iMac with 10.11.6 is able to wake from sleep for SSH and AFP access.  "Wake for network access" is checked in System Preferences : Energy Saver.  There is no Bonjour Proxy or network router, it has a public IP address.

The question is, how can I configure it to wake for access on an arbitrary port?

I would guess that there is a list of shared services to monitor somewhere at the unix/darwin level, but I have not yet found it.

Comment: What do you mean by "access on an arbitrary port"? Wake-on-Lan is triggered by a "magic" packet on the network, not by access to a specific port. What kind of problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: This is different than the wake-on-lan / wake-on-media packet.  This machine is capable of waking just by the act of a TCP session attempting to  connect on certain ports (22, 427, 528, etc.).  But not all TCP ports trigger a wake.  It appears to be related to the list of services in the Sharing pane of System Preferences.  I want to add to that list so a server listening on, for example, port 25000 will also trigger a wake.